# Why does my cpu work itself to death

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling

I have a relatively old AMD FX-6300 Vishera 6-Core 3.5 GHz CPU (bought 3 years ago).

Lately my computer started to turn off while I'm playing some new games so I suspected an overheat issue.

I've installed CoreTemp and saw that my computer would shutdown when CPU temp got around 80C (thats around 176F for those across the pond).

Re-applying thermal paste, cleaning up heatsink, replacing the CPU fan and disabling smart fan and running it at highest RPM at all times did not helped. Then I underclocked my CPU (reduced clock speed to 133MHz) and got rid of the overheat problem completely, now my CPU never gets over ~40C (104F).

My question is why does my CPU pushes itself to the absolute limits and why it does not just automatically slow itself down.

Comment: what is the exact model of CPU? The PhenomII series ended in 2010, so that doesn't mesh with your timeline. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenom_II

Comment: @FrankThomas sorry about that, I accidentally wrote my previous CPU. Updating the question now.

Comment: That CPU is still from 2012. So the likely answer is that current games push it to the limit. Did you check your Motherboard settings? At least some support an automatic shut off if a certain temperature is exceeded.

Comment: @Seth that is indeed the case here, when my CPU gets hot enough; protection kicks in and cuts the power. but my question is why it is allowed to reach such temperatures in default configuration

Comment: see here for some of the bios options of most concern for your situation: http://www.overclock.net/t/1202751/amd-fx-cpu-throttling-fixes-please-sticky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, generically, there are three basic areas you check to address these issues.

First, make sure your chipset drivers are up to date, and check for updates for your BIOS. Your power management systems rely on both these components, so an update may address your issue.

Second, confirm your BIOS/Firmware settings for power management and over clocking. Consult your motherboard manual so you are clear on what each of the settings does.

Third, consider replacing your CPU cooler. Numerous reviews on Newegg for your CPU indicate that the stock cooler is not sufficient for that user. In general I find that higher wattage AMD CPUs require more than average cooling, and your chip is 95W. I do not believe that AMD supports frequency throttling to reduce heat generation, beyond disabling turbo frequencies.

Instead of turning your base clock down, consider reducing your clock modifier instead. Some folks online have indicated that reducing voltage to the CPU is viable, but thats well beyond my OC skills.